# Stop NetBeans from grouping comments together

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-7.2

Trying to find out how to change NetBeans (7.2) from deleting lines between comments.

I Type

```
// comment 1

// comment 2
```

NetBeans auto format changes to

```
// comment 1
// comment 2
```

Is there a setting I am mising where I can stop the program from deleting that line?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712285/editing-the-netbeans-source-formatting-standard

Comment: what version of Netbeans are you on?

Comment: I'm using 7.2. I can't seem to find anything about comment formatting in tools->options->editor.

Comment: Instead of formatting the whole file, just select the part that is unformatted and format that.

Comment: Same thing is happening for me in NetBeans 8.0.2 with Java code. I cannot find any setting that helps in `NetBeans > Preferences > Editor > Formatting > Category: Comments` nor in `Category: Blank Lines`.

Answer (score 0):

No, but if you can change to multiline comment style

```
/* comment 1 */


/* comment 2 */
```

every new line between them will be preserved.

Comment: Is this still the only way to avoid getting grouped comments? I prefer the double slash to this method and would still like to keep my comments separate when formatting. I'm on 8.2.