# Generated getters and setters code format

Tags: c++, regex, netbeans, formatting

Is there a way to change format how netbeans 8.1 generate code? Instead of having

```
void setSomething1(bool something1) 
{
    something1_ = something1;
}

bool getSomething1() const 
{
    return something1_;
}
```

I would like to have this code

```
void setSomething1(bool something1) { something1_ = something1; }
bool getSomething1() const { return something1_; }
```

and also the set/get prefix could change or disappear

```
void setSomething1(bool something1) { something1_ = something1; }
bool something1() const { return something1_; }
```

netbeans only allow me to change braces position, same line or new line, but for this short functions i would like to compress it to one line only. With many setters and getters, the code starts to be confusing.

If netbeans itself cant do it, would it be possible via regular expression or some other workaroud?

Other (long body) functions will remain in the format. There it makes the code better to read.

```
retType name(args)
{
    body;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex will satisfy the first requirement ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bL3uU1/2)):

```
([\w ]+\s+[gs]et\w+\([\w ]*\)\s*(?:const)?)\s+\{\s+(.*)\s+\}
```

With `$1 { $2 }` as replacement

Then this one (note the trailing space):

```
 get(\w+)\(
```

With `$1` (trailing space aslo) as replacement

Comment: Thank you very much, i'd like to have it automatically by netbeans, but this will help me too. I just adjusted your regex to this

`([\w ]+\s+[gs]et\w+\([\w ]*\)(?: const)?)\s+\{\s+(.*)\s+\}`

i had some troubles with tabs and spaces, this works fine :)

Comment: @Lukin well if it works, you may upvote and/or accept the answer :)

Comment: I gave you upvote, but answer to accept should be about solution directly in netbeans, this is workaround. But thank you for it. It will save me plenty time but i cant reformat whole code automatically. It would format it back.

Comment: @Lukin you may look at [editing the NetBeans source formatting standard](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2712285/2307070)

Comment: Formatting settings via netbeans is very limited as i said in question. I was hoping some advanced setting is possible using some config file or some plugin but i didnt find anything.